# curl - Is data encrypted when using the --insecure option?

Tags: security, ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a situation where the client makes a call through curl to a https url. The SSL certificate of the https url is self signed and therefore curl cannot do certificate validation and fails. curl provides an option `-k/--insecure` which disables certificate validation.

My question is that on using `--insecure` option, is the data transfer that is done between client and server encrypted(as it should be for https urls)? I understand the security risk because of certificate validation not being done, but for this question I am only concerned about whether data transfer is encrypted or not.

Comment: Very bad strategy; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Comment: @jww, not necessarily bad if you are in a situation where you don't control the certs being used (self-signed in this case), yet still have a need to test using curl. I agree using self-signed certs without also installing the CA chain (as in an enterprise environment) is a bad idea, but in large orgs, it's often out of the control of the person that's writing some code or using an API.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Yes, the transfered data is still sent encrypted. `-k`/`--insecure` will "only make" `curl` skip certificate validation, it will not turn off SSL all together.

More information regarding the matter is available under the following link:

- [curl.haxx.se - Details on Server SSL Certificates](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)

Answer (score 2):

It will be encrypted but insecure. If you trust the certificate you should add the certificate to your certificate store instead of connecting insecurely.

macOS: 
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/new-root-certificate.crt

Ubuntu, Debian: 
sudo cp foo.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates

CentOS 6:
yum install ca-certificates
update-ca-trust force-enable
cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
update-ca-trust extract

CentOs 5:
cat foo.crt >>/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Windows:
certutil -addstore -f "ROOT" new-root-certificate.crt