# list all builds(artifacts) in a repo on jfrog-artifactory using AQL(artifactory query language)

Tags: curl, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

When ever I run the curl command it's throwing a syntax error. I've followed [this documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) to list all artifacts in 'war-release' repo. No idea what's the issue.

```
$curl -u uname:password -X POST https://<artifactory.com>/artifactory/api/search/aql -d items.find({"repo":"war-release"})
```

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Your expression contains characters which have meaning to bash, so you need to put them inside a string so bash leave them alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this curl statement:

`curl -u uname:password -X POST -d "items.find({"repo":"war-release"})" https:///artifactory/api/search/aql`

Comment: our server accepting only secure connections, so I appended command with "--insecure -v". It's not writing any thing throwing a 404. It supposed to be run AQL command.

$curl -u uname:password -X POST -d "items.find({"repo":"war-release"})" --insecure -v https://artifactory.com/api/search/aql

<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /api/search/aql was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to do but --insecure doesnt bypass ssl. It just skips certificate validation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520147/curl-insecure-option. It sounds like "war-release" couldnt be found so you are getting a 404.

Comment: The error you're getting as a response is not one that's returned by Artifactory - are you behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: yes i'm behind the reverse proxy. I'm able to see the repos. 

mysql> select distinct(repo) from nodes; war | | war-dev | | war-release Listed so many repos......

And tried this 
 $curl --capath /etc/pki/tls/certs -u uname:password -X POST https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({"repo":"war-dev"})"

Still it's throwing the same error.

Comment: The original error you posted is thrown by bash... did you try enclosing the query with " or ' ?

Comment: yes. Now I'm getting below error.

$ curl -u uname:password -X POST https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({"repo":"war-release"})"


{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Bad Request"
  } ]

Comment: Maybe mark this as answered and ask another question since the purpose of the comments is to clarify not to ask more questions. You will get more visibility that way, and a quicker answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another option that doesn't requires to enclose the query with " or ' and works in most environments is to save the query to file, lets call it aql.query

```
items.find(
     {
          "repo":"war-release"
     }
)
```

and then run the following curl command from the same directory that contains the aql.query file (don't forget to replace the templates in the command with your user name, password, host and port).

curl -X POST -uuser:password 'http://host:port/artifactory/api/search/aql' -Taql.query

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -X POST -k -u user:pwd 'https://xxx/artifactory/api/search/aql' -d 'items.find({"repo":"repo-local"})' gives json output.
```

use single quotes -- This worked for me fine

Answer (score 0):

To get a proper answer, you should use a content-type:

```
curl -X POST -k -u user:pwd -H "content-type: text/plain" 'https://xxx/artifactory/api/search/aql' -d 'items.find({"repo":"repo-local"})'
```

See: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-a-little-about-aql-and-content-type-headers/a-little-about-aql-and-content-type-headers