# maven deploy connection timeout

Tags: java, maven, proget

I'm trying to deploy a maven package to a proget server. However whenever I run mvn deploy after a pause I'm getting a error:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.redacted:rx:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to redacted (https://proget.redacted/maven2/test_feed_dont_use-SNAPSHOT): Connect to proget.redacted.com:443 [proget.redacted.com/8.8.8.8, proget.redacted/8.8.8.8] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

I can connect to the URL using firefox, but not curl. However if I use the `curl --insecure` option I can. Any idea what might be wrong?

I have tried this command line and it is still giving the same issue.

```
mvn deploy -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

I am using a proxy, however I have the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables set which seems to work for other applications. Does maven take note of these?

Comment: problems with certificate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520147/curl-insecure-option

Comment: also check DNS resolution and does your firefox using proxy?

Comment: @mauros I tried to disable SSL checking and am still getting the error. See update to post.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: @HRgiger I am using a proxy.

Comment: I've added the proxy to my settings.xml file and now I'm getting a `Not authorised` error. I've checked that the user name and password for proget are correct in the servers\server section of my setting's file.

Comment: I think that that is still the proxy. Check your username and password in the maven settings. Also, is it possible that your target needs to be add to <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts> ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problems were caused by a catalogue of issues. Thanks to the commenters for their help pinning some of these down:

1. maven does not pick the proxy settings up from the http_proxy environment variable. To get around this it needs to be set in the settings.xml file like this:

`

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>localProxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>1234</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

2. The certificate that our Proget site is using is not trusted by Java by default. To fix this:

   - Use a web browser to navigate to the Proget admin portal.
   - Use the padlock icon to view the certificate and export it.
   - From the location in environment variable $JAVA_HOME run the following:

   `./bin/keytool -import -alias [someName] -keystore jre/lib/security/cacerts -file ~/certFile.crt`
3. There is a bug in ProGet version 4.2.1 (Build 8) which prevents uploading SNAPSHOT packages. I didn't figure out how to work around this, but decided not to use SNAPSHOTs instead. Apparently the ProGet team are working on a fix for the next release.