# i have curl command its work fine in cmd but i want to run it in java code

Tags: java, curl

i have curl command its work fine in cmd but i want to run it in java code.The main thing bout command is it is calling a "POST" API which require authenticaton too.
i have used debugger too its not going in the loop to read the response

```
String[] command = {"curl",url, "-H" ,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","-X", username+ "&" + password ,"insecure"};
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process p;
        try
        {
            p = process.start();
            BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line="" ;
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);
                builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            String result = builder.toString();
            System.out.print(result);

        }
```

curl 'https://integration.sirionlabs.office:9443/nifi-api/access/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data 'username=username&password=password' --compressed --insecure

The expected result is the bearer token which I need

Comment: i want to run this command in java code:curl 'https://integration.sirionlabs.office:9443/nifi-api/access/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data 'username=username&password=password' --compressed --insecure

Comment: You are approaching the solution in the wrong direction, you should look for an HTTP client instead of running the command from Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: for a couple of reasons, for example windows do not have curl so your code simply does not run on windows. And the code will be very hard to maintain

Answer (score 1):

[Unirest](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/) is among the most common Java HTTP Clients in the moment I am writing this answer.

Here's an example of the cURL command you have shown using **Unirest** in Java.

The code is a bit tricky because of the --insecure flag in cURL and this is one of the possible solutions to obtain a similar result in Unirest (source: https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/issues/70):

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class UnirestCertificateIgnore {

    private static HttpClient unsafeHttpClient;

    static {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();

            unsafeHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();

        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static HttpClient getClient() {
        return unsafeHttpClient;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            HttpClient creepyClient = RestUnirestClient.getClient();
            Unirest.setHttpClient(creepyClient);

            HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("https://integration.sirionlabs.office:9443/nifi-api/access/token")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .body("username=username&password=password")
                .asString();

        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about emulating curl’s `--insecure` option?

Comment: @VGR --insecure will just ignore cURL certificate internal check. Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520147/curl-insecure-option

Comment: Very good point, @VGR!
I need to do some tests to provide a precise answer but I'd assume no.
Let me see if I can find some self signed certificate and be able to certify / improve my answer accordingly.

Comment: I hope this solution can be better, @VGR
Thanks for your time and teaching.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running an external `curl` process, use Java to submit your request.  This will work even on systems where `curl` isn’t installed, making your code truly multi-platform:

```
String body = String.format("username=%s&password=%s",
    URLEncoder.encode(username, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
    URLEncoder.encode(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url));
// -H
builder.setHeader("Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
// --data
builder.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body));
HttpRequest request = builder.build();

// --insecure
TrustManager acceptAll = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType)
    throws CertificateException {
        // Deliberately empty.
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType)
    throws CertificateException {
        // Deliberately empty.
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
};
SSLContext context;
try {
    context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { acceptAll }, null);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(context).build();
HttpResponse<String> response =
    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

int status = response.statusCode();
if (status >= 400) {
    throw new IOException("Request failed with code " + status);
}

String result = response.body();
```

The HttpRequest, HttpResponse, and HttpClient classes are from the [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) package.